# Illegal string offset 'name' laravel php

Tags: laravel

This is my view and controller of signup page. I am using laravel framework. I have checked this and it is giving error because of password field. I compiled it without password field and it worked. I am unable to understand what is the problem in it. I copied it fron laravel collective form page.

**View:**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'signup/submit']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('name', 'Name')}}
            {{Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Full Name'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('username', 'Username')}}
            {{Form::text('username', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Username'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address')}}
            {{Form::email('email', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your email..'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('password', 'Password')}}
            {{Form::password('password', '123', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password...'])}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'username',
            'email' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password'
        ]);

        //Getting the info and creating new message.
        $message = new Message;
        $message->name = $request->input('name');
        $message->username = $request->input('username');
        $message->message = $request->input('email');
        $message->message = $request->input('password');

        $message->save();

        //redirecting
        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Registeration successful');
    }
```

If anyone can understand the problem?

This is the error screen shot:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL3hz.png)

Comment: Can you give us the full error message, including which file and line it says the error is on?

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Please enable debugging on your .env file (if it is not already enabled). Re-run your code, copy and paste the contents of your storage/logs/laravel.log into your Stackoverflow question. The more debugging data, the merrier.

Comment: Validate in good way

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok i found it, it's because the password field doesn't take a display value.

Change this

```
{{Form::password('password', '123', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password...'])}}
```

to this

```
{{Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password...'])}}
```

From https://laravel.io/forum/08-12-2014-illegal-string-offset-name-when-validating-against-unique

Answer (score 0):

You save two times on ->message here

```
 $message->message = $request->input('email');
 $message->message = $request->input('password');
```

So you need to change the field where the password input is saved like:

```
 $message->message = $request->input('email');
 $message->password= $request->input('password');
```

Comment: Yeah it was an other error, i didn't understood all without the error screen